# How to freeze entire header row in openpyxl?

Tags: python, openpyxl

How to freeze entire header row in openpyxl? 
So far I can only freeze the column:

```
# only freeze the column (freeze vertically)
cell = ws.cell('{}{}'.format(col, row_idx+1))  
worksheet.freeze_panes = cell
```

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Make sure `cell` isn't on row one - `freeze_panes` will freeze rows above the given cell and columns to the left.

---

#### Example:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
c = ws['B2']
ws.freeze_panes = c
wb.save('test.xlsx')
```

---

This will give you a blank worksheet with both row 1 and column A frozen.

Comment: Or you could just do `wb["Sheet_name"].freeze_panes = "B2"`

Comment: Probably obvious: use 'A2' instead of 'B2' to only freeze the header row.

Comment: @mvbentes You should consider posting this as an answer.

Comment: A suggestion to complete Paul's solution: freeze panes only after inserting some data. Otherwise, the freezed row will be empty if you insert data with an `ws.append([…])`.

Comment: @mvbentes comment of wb["Sheet_name"].freeze_panes = "B2" will work in write only mode too.

Answer (score 0):

To freeze top side header rows,
first step is scroll up the worksheet & then freeze that row.

```
# To freeze first N rows
ws.views.sheetView[0].topLeftCell = 'A1' # scroll to top left corner
ws.freeze_panes = 'F7' # freeze command
# To freeze rows from last save point of your workbook
ws.freeze_panes = 'F7' 

# To freeze columns 
ws.freeze_panes = 'G1' # This line freeze A to G columns
ws.freeze_panes = 'B1' # This line freeze A column.
```